# Getting the original MAC address of Network Adapter in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mac-address

There is possibility of changing the MAC address using may tools and methods. Is there any way to get the default MAC Address of the Network Card even its address has been changed. In many MAC address changer tools there is option to Restore the Default MAC address. So how can we retrieve the Default MAC even though the MAC address is changed?

Comment: No that is kind of the point with changing the mac address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that either the API's available are asking the NIC to return it's MAC value, or they are querying an OS cache of the MAC values that the NIC's previously reported.

If you change the MAC of the NIC using any of the techniques you mention, the NIC will then report this new value either to the OS or in response to the API's queries.

The *current* MAC address of a NIC (not it's *original* address) can be determined in .Net using the following library:

`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces`

Comment: I understood your point, but how can we get the original MAC Address using C#?

Comment: I think you missed the point. Imagine that your name is changed from Prem Singh to Shahrukh Khan. You now believe your name has always been Shahrukh Khan. If I then ask you what your name is, you will tell me it's Shahrukh Khan. If I ask what your *original* name is, you will still say Shahrukh Khan because you believe it is Shahrukh Khan. The NIC does not remember what its MAC *used* to be. It only knows what its MAC is currently set to be. You can obtain the *current* MAC using `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces`.

Comment: So you are saying that it is not possible to get the Actual MAC address. This means that if we register to a site that check MAC address with original MAC address and change the MAC with any freely available tool and can use the same computer to register for another account. We cannot detect it and block them?